# How do I add a simulation model to a multi-part component in Altium?

Tags: altium, spice

I have a TL072 op-amp as a multi-part (3 parts) in my libarary i.e. 2x op-amps + separate power supply. Now i would like to add TI's spice simulation model. However, I cannot add it, because Altium complains about the pin count, since it appears to only see the sub-part (see error message below). Both the multi-part and the spice model are defined with 8-pins.

[image: altium error message]

Comment: You should post this question to the Altium forum.  https://forum.live.altium.com/

Comment: Check if the lib really contains 2x op-amps. Most TI models contain only one opAmp with supply pins. 

Try to copy and paste it to have it so you have it twice in the model file. Then name pins of the two model instances as in your Altium symbol. 
If this does not work you could need a kind of wrapper which has all pins and the calls the
two models.

Comment: @schwdk : I actually got this to work! Thank you. If you make your comment an answer, i'll award you the bounty.

Comment: @schwdk please with screen shot if you can . this is very common problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the lib really contains 2x op-amps. Most TI models contain only one opAmp with supply pins. Try to copy and paste it to have it so you have it twice in the model file. Then name pins of the two model instances as in your Altium symbol. If this does not work you could need a kind of wrapper which has all pins and the calls the two models